# Web Bluetooth API not seeing any new characteristic values

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

I successfully wrote a basic JS application reading what is the Stereo/Left/Right value of a Sony Bluetooth speaker. I was able to do this by going to chrome://bluetooth-internals/ , finding and connecting to the device, then I began to click Read on each characteristic while changing the stereo on the speaker. Eventually I found the correct one that is changing when I change the setting.

I was able to get the service and characteristic ID from this and successfully write a basic prototype JS application to read this data live when notifications have started. I used code in various samples in  the following page to build it. https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/index.html

My second experiment is with a Goodmans fitness watch, [something very close to this](https://www.beattys.ie/products/goodmans-fitness-tracker-watch?currency=EUR&variant=39425876721708&utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=google&utm_campaign=Google%20Shopping&gclid=Cj0KCQjwuO6WBhDLARIsAIdeyDK8zR20fPeCT_4jRvgOjbKYTvHzPNHk78ZoR5AYeNL0h5AdKEnMlTMaAoJqEALw_wcB) (exact model does not seem to be online).

This provides information like heart rate, amount of steps complete etc.

I successfully paired it with the recommended app and can confirm that I can receive data using this Orunning app.

My next step I was hoping to achieve was to repeat the same process as that I did with the speaker. However values do not seem to be updating in chrome://bluetooth-internals/

I am successfully connecting to the device, I then check all the characteristics that have read values, I then proceeded to try read them again but no updates are occurring even though the data in the watch has changed.

My questions are:

1. Is there a better way to figure out the service you are looking for? I have reading this to get a better understanding: https://learn.adafruit.com/introduction-to-bluetooth-low-energy/further-information
2. Am I missing something regarding how it reads data? I even tried the ones with notification permissions but literally no values have changed.

I even disconnected everything, refreshed the browser and reconnected, and when I click Read on all the characteristics, its still the same values.

I have searched online to try understand this process, so if there is documentation you can point me to understand specifically this I would appreciate it.

Comment: Am I understanding this correctly that you trying to fetch data from your bluetooth-enabled fitness watch without the manufacturer's app?

Comment: Yes, however they do not even use their own app. They obviously provide details to another app I presume.

Comment: I see. I assume the things you are looking for are not exposed that way and more likely the app sends/requests data from the device directly.

Comment: Thanks, I think that possibly indirectly answers my question. There is obviously more types of ways to send and request data.